# Standard normal distribution problem with $P(X<\theta Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X, Y$ be the independent standard normal random variables with density $\phi(x)$ and distribution function $\Phi (x)$, $\phi(x) $ is standard normal distibution and $\Phi (x)$ is integrate form of $\phi (x)$ from $-\inf$ to $x$.

Problem is,

Let $\theta $ be an arbitrary real number and argue that $P(X<\theta Y) = 0.5$

I got integrate form of deriving $P(X<\theta Y)$ , but no idea how to deal with $\theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy solution.

Hint:

The distribution of

$$Z=X-\theta Y$$

is?

**Solution**

$$Z \sim N(0;1+\theta^2)$$

Thus

$$\mathbb{P}(X<\theta Y)=\mathbb{P}(Z<0)=\Phi\Bigg(\frac{0-0}{\sqrt{1+\theta^2}}\Bigg)=\Phi(0)=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

No need to do any integration. $Z=X-\theta Y$ has  a symmetric (continuous ) distribution, namely $N(0, 1+\theta^{2})$. Hence $P (Z<0) =P(Z>0)=\frac  1 2$.